# If $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and $Cov(X,Y|Z)=0$, does it mean $Cov(Y,Z)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance

Let $X,Y,Z$ be $L^2$ random variables, not constants.

If $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and $Cov(X,Y|Z)=0$, does it mean $Cov(Y,Z)=0$ ?

My opinion is no, but I cannot find a counterexample.

$Cov(X,Y)=0$ and $Cov(X,Y|Z)=0$ imply that $Cov(E[X|Z],E[Y|Z])=0$, which is far away from $Cov(Y,Z)=0$.

Comment: I think $X=0$ and $Y=Z$ gives an easy counterexample?

Comment: @user6247850 You are right, I should have mentioned that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are not constant.

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume all these variables are centred. Then, covariance is the inner product in $\mathscr{L}^2$ and conditioning is the usual orthogonal projection. If $X$ is already orthogonal to $Z,$ the conditional covariance (which really is the inner product of the projections of $X$ and $Y$ on the span of $Z$) will be zero, and yet, $Y$ can perfectly have a nonzero projection onto $Z.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for a constant, it's almost always still going to work if you require them to be non-constant.  For another example, here you can take $Y=Z$ and $X$ independent of $Y$.